# Parsing Json nested objects in Bash

Tags: json, bash, sed, jq

I'm accessing an API that returns JSON with nested objects like this:

```
{
  "9273": {
    "status": "ok",
    "tag": "group-8",
    "name": "London"
  },
  "4029": {
    "status": "unknown",
    "tag": "group-12",
    "name": "Tokyo"
  },
  "6322": {
    "status": "ok",
    "tag": "group-12",
    "name": "Singapore"
  },
  "1038": {
    "status": "unknown",
    "tag": "group-19",
    "name": "Melbourne"
  },
  "2938": {
    "status": "ok",
    "tag": "group-12",
    "name": "New York"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to parse the JSON using `jq`, `regex`, `sed` etc. in a Bash script, filter it on `status` (ok) and `tag` (highest group with an 'ok'), and flatten the matching objects to get a multi-line sorted string value of their `name` along with a static prefix (e.g. City).

Desired output below:

```
City: New York
City: Singapore
```

I'll appreciate any help in working this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your data, and using the -r command-line option, the following program produces the output shown below:

```
[.[]]
| map(select(.status == "ok"))
| (max_by( .tag | sub("group-";"") | tonumber) | .tag) as $mx
| .[]
| select(.tag==$mx)
| "City: \(.name)"
```

Output:

```
City: Singapore
City: New York
```

If you want the cities listed in alphabetical order, then you can add the appropriate `sort_by` filter to the jq pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Where does the `sort_by` go in the chain?

Comment: Never mind. Figured out the sorting: `[.[]] | map(select(.status == "ok")) | (max_by( .tag | sub("group-";"") | tonumber) | .tag) as $mx | [.[]] | map(select(.tag==$mx)) | sort_by(.name) | .[] | "City: \(.name)"`

Comment: By the way, I made a shorter alternative using `group_by` based on your answer: `[.[]] | map(select(.status == "ok")) | group_by(.tag) | max_by( .[].tag | sub("group-";"") | tonumber) | sort_by(.name)? | .[] | "City: \(.name)"`. Do you see any problem with it as such?

Comment: Yes, there are some efficiency issues.  Also, the semantics of max_by(STREAM) is a bit obscure.

Comment: Thanks for your time and review. So you reckon `group_by` is inefficient in this case?